# How to upgrade magento 1.5 mage all latest to the beta version

Tags: php, magento

is it possible to do this through mage? if so how . when I try

```
    ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest
```

it just tries to install the same version 1.5.1.0    putting upgrade would do the same.   how to tell mage install to install the beta version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  I need to set mage to use BETA:

```
  ./mage config-set preferred_state beta
```

found on this site: http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/1294-magento-15-mage-command-line